# Creating a table in mysql with java named by the user?

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1064, create-table

The question is, is there a way to create a new table named by the user from a text field. I know its a huge injection port, but i really need new tables, it will work only offline. I tried

```
String newtable = jTextField1.getText();
PreparedStatement create = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '"+newtable+"'(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, IDapol INTEGER, ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ DATE, ΕΣΟΔΑ DOUBLE, PRIMARY KEY(ID), CONSTRAINT IDapol FOREIGN KEY(IDapol) REFERENCES apol(IDapol)");
```

but i get an error saying: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "1718"(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, IDapol, INTEGER, ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ' at line 1

1718 is the value of my textField1.
Any help i could use? Thanks

Comment: Table names should start with characters

Comment: As far as I know mysql won't allow for digit only table names. As [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) states: *Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.*

Comment: Print your generated query and try to run in data base.It is syntax error you can resolved your own.

Answer (score 1):

As per here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html , "Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits."

Also, currently your code is wide open for an SQL injection attack.

Comment: You're right, I now entered ko as value to textField and sql comes back with a "...syntax error near " at line 1"

Comment: Removing the apostrophes in `'"+newtable+"'` should do it.  If not, post the full message.

Comment: It sais:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have and error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1

.Thats it..

Comment: What's the actual SQL statement?

Comment: I would reduce the SQL statement to the bare minimum (e.g. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '"+newtable+"'(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, IDapol INTEGER)` and then add the rest one by one until it breaks.  Then you will know what broke it.

Comment: Thanks again, i broke it down. The syntax error was at FOREIGN KEY, i had to re-write it to make it work. Stupid me, except the digit error, i wasn't closing all parenthesis..

Answer (score 0):

Table names are never in `'`. Either use backticks (`) or simply nothing:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + newtable + " (...)
```

Your table's name should also start with a character!

Comment: You're right, I now entered ko as value to textField and sql comes back with a "...syntax error near " at line 1"

I used nothing, just "+newtable+"(...

Answer (score -1):

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `1718`
(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 IDapol INTEGER, 
 ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ DATE, 
 ΕΣΟΔΑ DOUBLE, 
 PRIMARY KEY(ID), 
 CONSTRAINT IDapol 
 FOREIGN KEY(IDapol) REFERENCES apol(IDapol);

give table name in `` codes